# Set Buttons to run Different Scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with 2 tables and each row has a 'Select' button which needs to run a script when clicked. I've got this working with the first table but can't work out how to get it working with both tables.

Here's the HTML for the tables:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h2>Select Main</h2>

<div>

  <br />
  <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <th scope="col">Code</th>
      <th scope="col">Description</th>
      <th class="text-center" scope="col">Select</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr class="" id="SK5543333">
        <td>BJ2345</td>
        <td>Laptop 13 inch display</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="" id="SK3241235213">
        <td>AZ77656</td>
        <td>Laptop 15 inch display</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>


    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>


<h2>Select Accessories</h2>

<div>

  <br />
  <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <th scope="col">Code</th>
      <th scope="col">Description</th>
      <th class="text-center" scope="col">Select</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr class="" id="SK3412541">
        <td>MM42412341</td>
        <td>Mouse</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="" id="SK95390485">
        <td>KB42341243</td>
        <td>Keyboard</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="" id="SK42353">
        <td>USB421341234</td>
        <td>USB Adapter</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="" id="SK543647585">
        <td>PWR363456534</td>
        <td>POWER ADAPTER</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

I need to run a different script when users select from the top/Main table and another script when users select from the bottom/Accessories table. Here are the 2 scripts that I would like to run when the Select button is clicked in either table (first script for the top table and 2nd script for the 2nd table):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button.btn-success:not([type="submit"])').click(function() {
    // Remove the classes from all of the TR elements
    $(this).parents('table').find('tr').removeClass('success warning danger');
    var productID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    console.log(productID);
    $this = $(this);
    // add the success class to the row and remove the danger class if it was present
    $this.closest('tr').addClass("success");
    $this.closest('tr').removeClass("danger");
    // update the hidden input with the selected productID
    $('#productID').val(productID);
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button.btn-success:not([type="submit"])').click(function() {
    var itemID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    // Create a reference to $(this) here:
    $this = $(this);
    $.post('updateAccessories.php', {
      itemID: itemID
    }, function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      if (data.error) {
        var ajaxError = (data.text);
        var errorAlert = 'There was an error updating your selections - ' + ajaxError + '. Please contact the Help Desk';
        $this.closest('tr').addClass("warning");
        $('#alert_ajax_error').html(errorAlert);
        $("#alert_ajax_error").show();
        return; // stop executing this function any further
      } else {
        if ($this.closest('tr').hasClass("success")) {
          $this.closest('tr').removeClass("success");
        } else {
          $this.closest('tr').addClass("success");
        }
      }
    }).fail(function(xhr) {
      var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
      var ajaxError = 'There was an error updating your selections - AJAX request error. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus + '. Please contact the Help Desk';
      $this.closest('tr').addClass("warning");
      $('#alert_ajax_error').html(ajaxError);
      $("#alert_ajax_error").show();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

At the moment clicking either button runs both scripts which I can understand as they both meet the criteria for:

```
$('button.btn-success:not([type="submit"])').click(function() {
```

but I'm not experienced enough to know how to make the necessary changes to have each button run a different script here?

Comment: Is there truly **no** unique data about either table? Could you not add a unique ID? I suppose you could always run an `:nth-of-type` on the two `<div>` (possibly `<table>`) elements themselves, but that seems highly dangerous in terms of making future modifications.

Comment: can you change the html markup?

Comment: I can change the HTML if necessary - it's under my control.

Comment: If you want to use different AJAX calls when you hit a different buttons then use different selectors and different code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change the markup then add a class from `main` and another for `accessories` in the button and do `$('button.main')` and `$('button.accessories')` instead of `$('button.btn-success:not([type="submit"])')`

If not then you need to be able to discern one from another.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button.btn-success:not([type="submit"])').click(function(e) {
    var  t = $(e.target).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().prev()[0].innerHTML;
    if(t.indexOf("Main") !== -1) {
      // Has MAIN - put your main code in here
      console.log("main stuff");
    } else if (t.indexOf("Accessories") !== -1) {
      // It's Accessories - put your accessories code in here
      console.log("accessories stuff");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Select Main</h2>
<div>
  <br />
  <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <th scope="col">Code</th>
      <th scope="col">Description</th>
      <th class="text-center" scope="col">Select</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr class="" id="SK5543333">
        <td>BJ2345</td>
        <td>Laptop 13 inch display</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="" id="SK3241235213">
        <td>AZ77656</td>
        <td>Laptop 15 inch display</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>


    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>


<h2>Select Accessories</h2>

<div>

  <br />
  <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <th scope="col">Code</th>
      <th scope="col">Description</th>
      <th class="text-center" scope="col">Select</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr class="" id="SK3412541">
        <td>MM42412341</td>
        <td>Mouse</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="" id="SK95390485">
        <td>KB42341243</td>
        <td>Keyboard</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="" id="SK42353">
        <td>USB421341234</td>
        <td>USB Adapter</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="" id="SK543647585">
        <td>PWR363456534</td>
        <td>POWER ADAPTER</td>
        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A very basic way to differentiate between buttons would be to add an attribute called "id" to them.

```
<button id="button1" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button>
<button id="button2" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button>
```

Now you can reference each like this:

```
$('#button1').click(function() { ...
$('#button2').click(function() { ...
```